# Decompose the vector AC as sum of vectors parallel and perpendicular to AB

Tags: vectors

I have two vectors AB = (0,-2,1) and AC = (2,-1,0)
The dot product of AB and AC = 2 and the length of each are $\sqrt{5}$ . That is what i have. I have little or no idea how to do this problem as i have some trouble finding any good examples out there. I need help with the question on the title. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly easy.

The first thing is to find a vector $u$ perpendicular to $AB$.

You will have $u.AB=0$

You can see easily that $u=(0,1,2)$ fits the bill.

Then the vector $v=u \times AB$ is obviously perpendicular to both of them, or you can choose another straightforward vector such as $(1,0,0)$, since it is obvious it is perpendicular to both.

Then write $AC=\alpha AB+\beta u +\delta v$ (as $AB$ is parallel to $AB$, it is the best candidate here!)

You get then $\alpha, \beta, \delta$ very quickly.

Comment: Ok, i get how i get vector u since the dot product is equal to 0. But the rest you did there is a bit harder to understand .

Comment: @KimR To use $(1,0,0)$ is good, since the dot product is also $0$ against the two other vectors $AB$ and $u$. But you can also use the cross product (also named vector product and written with a $\times$) that from two vectors will give an other one that is perpendicular to both of the initial vectors. After you got two perpendicular vectors to $AB$, you have a orthogonal basis and $AC$ can be written in this new orthogonal basis.

Answer (score 0):

Our goal is to find a scalar $k$ and a vector $\vec v\perp \overrightarrow{AB}$ such that
$$\overrightarrow{AC}=k\overrightarrow{AB}+\vec v$$

If we multiply (dot product) this equation by $\overrightarrow{AB}$ we get:
$$\overrightarrow{AB}\cdot \overrightarrow{AC}=k\|\overrightarrow{AB}\|^2$$

We deduce that the projection is:
$$k=\frac{\overrightarrow{AB}\cdot \overrightarrow{AC}}{\|\overrightarrow{AB}\|^2}$$

and the orthogonal component is:
$$\vec v=\overrightarrow{AC}-k\overrightarrow{AB}$$